# Proof to the general solution of a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Assume that $f(u,v)$ is a two-variable function. How do I solve this PDE?
$$\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}=\frac{-2}{v}$$
What I did was pretending that the partial derivative is a normal derivative, in this case
$f=Cv^{-2}$
Then I notice that I can multiply the entire thing by an arbitary function $g(u)$, so in the end my guess is
$f(u,v)=g(u)v^{-2}$. This seems to work, but how to I prove that it's the MOST GENERAL solution?

Comment: This is the most general solution. When you do the derivation, you integrate it up for a fixed value of $u$. And when you get the constant $C$ then note that this is only a constant with respect to $v$ (i.e. changing $v$ does not change the value of $C$). However, you cannot say that $C$ does not depend on $u$ so in general $C = C(u)$.

Comment: @Winther That's helpful. Thank you!